# Column Type from Str to int or float pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, group-by

I am using group by function of pandas, instead of adding numbers, pandas think it is a string and return like: 3,000,000,000.0092,315,000.00 instead of 3,092,315,000. i have tried several methods of conversions but each time it returns "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,000,000,000.00'"
i am unable to attach csv file, that might be the real problem.

```
df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].astype('float')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `,` with `` first.

`df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].str.replace(',', '').astype('float')`

Comment: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: This warning is raised when trying to modify a copy of df rather than the original data. This can occur when you use a selection method like `df['column']` to select a subset of the data, and then try to modify that subset. You can use `df.loc[:, 'AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].str.replace(',', '').astype('float')` instead.

Comment: it means we have to do this function on the whole DF instead of a piece. thank you. appreciated. May God increase your knowledge and wisdom